# Pivot point supertrend's use of pivothigh

Tags: pine-script

ta.pivothigh

I am trying to translate the following [script](https://www.tradingview.com/pine/?id=PUB%3BHN4w1eNW3B9HP5oSa2MNMIHMYUqLPHUT) (Pivot Point SuperTrend) to Python. In line **15** we see the command

```
float ph = pivothigh(prd, prd)
```

is `pivothigh` here the same indicator that is discussed in the docs [here](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000589195-pivot-points-high-low/), and if yes what are the calculations involved in computing it exactly? Do I simply take the highest value while moving in steps of size `[prd + prd]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
def checkhl(data_back, data_forward, hl):
    if hl == 'high' or hl == 'High':
        ref = data_back[len(data_back)-1]
        for i in range(len(data_back)-1):
            if ref < data_back[i]:
                return 0
        for i in range(len(data_forward)):
            if ref <= data_forward[i]:
                return 0
        return 1
    if hl == 'low' or hl == 'Low':
        ref = data_back[len(data_back)-1]
        for i in range(len(data_back)-1):
            if ref > data_back[i]:
                return 0
        for i in range(len(data_forward)):
            if ref >= data_forward[i]:
                return 0
        return 1
```

```
def pivot(osc, LBL, LBR, highlow):
    left = []
    right = []
    pivots=[]
    for i in range(len(osc)):
        pivots.append(0.0)
        if i < LBL + 1:
            left.append(osc[i])
        if i > LBL:
            right.append(osc[i])
        if i > LBL + LBR:
            left.append(right[0])
            left.pop(0)
            right.pop(0)
            if checkhl(left, right, highlow):
                pivots[i - LBR] = osc[i - LBR]
    return pivots
```

```
period=2
df['pivot_high'] = pivot(df['high'], period, period, 'high')
df['pivot_low'] = pivot(df['low'], period, period, 'low')
```

This will be helpful in finding pivot highs and pivot lows

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).